# How to retain order of array using each and image.onload

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, html5-canvas

I'm trying to use image.onload function but async issue is occuring. I'm passing the data through array but it is not executing according to array order in the image.onload function. How  can I fix this issue?

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(element => {
    const brushtype = element[0]['brush']
    const img = new Image();
      img.onload = () => {
        brushctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      }
    img.src = brushtype;
   }
```

Comment: How does your object `data` look like ? because I'm not sure how `element[0]['brush']` can be correct! how can you expect an object key to be an object?

Comment: It is png type image

Comment: png images are assigning according to the correct order for the brushtype variable. But in img.onload function it is execution not an order

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way you're requesting those images.

By doing

```
Object.entries(data).forEach(element => {
   }
```

it's happening at the same time virtually. Whatever image finished loading will be drawn right-after.

If you want your images to be drawn in a specific order - e.g. the order it's listed in the array - you need to request a new one **after** the previous finished loading.

Here's an example:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');

let myImages = ['https://picsum.photos/id/1/50/50', 'https://picsum.photos/id/22/50/50', 'https://picsum.photos/id/83/50/50', 'https://picsum.photos/id/64/50/50'];

function loadImages(index) {
  let image = new Image();
  image.onload = function(e) {
    context.drawImage(e.target, index % 2 * 50, parseInt(index / 2) * 50);
    if (index + 1 < myImages.length) {
      loadImages(index + 1);
    }
  }
  image.src = myImages[index];
}

loadImages(0);
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='200' height='200'></canvas>
```

Comment: Loading one after the other will significantly increase the time for the images to load as they are no longer concurrent. If the browser allows 6 concurrent loads then loading one after another will take 6 times longer. It is easy to draw them in order while still loading them concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

To draw images in order of request you either need to wait until all images have loaded and then draw them only when the earlier image have been draw. This answer gives an example of both approaches.

**Note** That if there are any load errors none of the images may be drawn. In the second method an error will mean none to all but one are drawn.

### Load first then draw

The snippet bellow loads first then draws. It stores the images in an array `images` and keeps a count of images loading. Counting up for each new image, and when an image load it counts down.

When the counter is zero when know all images have loaded and can then draw them all

```
var imgCount = 0;
const images = [];
Object.entries(data).forEach(element => {
    const img = new Image;
    img.src = element[0]['brush'];
    images.push(img);
    imgCount ++;
    img.onload = () => {
       imgCount --;
       if (!imgCount) {
          for(const img of images) {  brushctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0) }
       }
    }
}
```

### Draw only when first or previous loaded.

The alternative is to again create an array to hold all the images. But this time we track what has been drawn. Each time an image is loaded, we check if any of the images in the array before it have loaded, then we draw all images until we find a empty image slot.

```
var drawnCount = 0;
const images = [];
Object.entries(data).forEach(element => {
    const img = new Image;
    const imgIdx = images.length;
    img.src = element[0]['brush'];
    img.onload = () => {
       images[imgIdx] = img;
       while (images[drawnCount]) { brushctx.drawImage(images[drawnCount++], 0, 0) }
    }
    images.push(null);
}
```